# Move Folder - csproj and Nuget

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I have a nuget getting created and Content folder getting created in the nuget. I want my files to not be in Content folder but be in the Test folder in that nuget. (So, user won't see files by default.)

How Can I move files from ContentFolder to Test folder ?

My csproj has :

```
<ItemGroup>
        <Protobuf Include="*.proto" GrpcServices="Both" />
        <Content Include="@(Protobuf)" />  // If I remove this line - Content folder disappers, but I want to keep this data into a Test folder in my nuget
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PackagePath` to control where content is placed in NuGet packages.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Protobuf Include="*.proto" GrpcServices="Both" />
  <Content Include="@(Protobuf)" PackagePath="Test" /> 
</ItemGroup>
```